# How to specify media formatter on /media/[id] page?

Tags: media

I have [Media 2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) installed and every file (since they're entities) has its own page accessible via `/media/[id]`.

I can't figure out how to set a formatter for displaying the media there. It always renders the original image, or a default image for other media types like PDF or EPS.

For all content types, you can do it via their display settings as well as the file types settings under `admin/config/media/file-types` respectively, but these have no effect whatsoever on the display on `/media/[id]` entitiy pages.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
(Specifically, I want to use [PDFpreview module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfpreview) to display previews of PDF files uploaded as well as display images with an image style and not rendering the original one).